# Could not connect to the video device (/dev/video0)

Tags: debian

I have check my ls -la /dev/v* but no /dev/video0 file, how to connect video0 file in debian OS

> crw------- 1 root root  7,   0 Feb  8 16:21 /dev/vcs
>   crw------- 1 root root  7,   1 Feb  8 16:21 /dev/vcs1
>   crw------- 1 root root  7,   2 Feb  8 16:21 /dev/vcs2
>   crw------- 1 root root  7,   3 Feb  8 16:21 /dev/vcs3
>   crw------- 1 root root  7,   4 Feb  8 16:21 /dev/vcs4
>   crw------- 1 root root  7,   5 Feb  8 16:21 /dev/vcs5
>   crw------- 1 root root  7,   6 Feb  8 16:21 /dev/vcs6
>   crw------- 1 root root  7,  63 Feb  8 17:34 /dev/vcs63
>   crw------- 1 root root  7,   7 Feb  8 16:21 /dev/vcs7
>   crw------- 1 root root  7, 128 Feb  8 16:21 /dev/vcsa
>   crw------- 1 root root  7, 129 Feb  8 16:21 /dev/vcsa1
>   crw------- 1 root root  7, 130 Feb  8 16:21 /dev/vcsa2
>   crw------- 1 root root  7, 131 Feb  8 16:21 /dev/vcsa3
>   crw------- 1 root root  7, 132 Feb  8 16:21 /dev/vcsa4
>   crw------- 1 root root  7, 133 Feb  8 16:21 /dev/vcsa5
>   crw------- 1 root root  7, 134 Feb  8 16:21 /dev/vcsa6
>   crw------- 1 root root  7, 191 Feb  8 17:34 /dev/vcsa63
>   crw------- 1 root root  7, 135 Feb  8 16:21 /dev/vcsa7
>   crw------- 1 root root 10,  63 Feb  8 16:21 /dev/vga_arbiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have update latest kernel in Debian.this problem is solved.